# page up scroll not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to scroll the page set to view port in page up button.I done this in Drupal.within a single block view-rows it is working fine.I want to done this for two block.While integrating with two block the class 'scroll' is not appended to banners last view.

```js
$('.views-row').height($(window).height());
    $('.views-row').first().addClass('scroll');
     $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
       var scroll = $('.scroll');
     if(e.keyCode == 34 ){
            //mousewheel down handler
            next = scroll.next();
            //check if the next section exist and animate the anchoring
   
            if (next.length>0) {
                var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    
                    $('body, html').animate({
                        scrollTop: next.offset().top
                    }, 'slow');
                    
                   
                    next.addClass('scroll')
                        .siblings().removeClass('scroll');
                    
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }, 0);
            }
            else if(next.length==0){
    $('#block-views-home-banner-block .classtest').removeClass('scroll');
    $('#block-views-customerspeak-block .classtest').addClass('scroll')
   }
        } else if(e.keyCode == 33 ){
           //mousewheel up handler
            prev = scroll.prev();
               
            if (prev.length) {
    if($('.view-customerspeak .classtest').hasClass('scroll')) {
                    console.log("success");     
        $('#block-views-customerspeak-block .classtest').removeClass('scroll');
     $('#block-views-home-banner-block').last('.classtest').addClass('scroll');
     var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    $('body, html').animate({
                        scrollTop: prev.offset().top
                    }, 'slow');

                    prev.addClass('scroll')
                        .siblings().removeClass('scroll');
                    
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }, 0);
     }
    else{
                   var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    $('body, html').animate({
                        scrollTop: prev.offset().top
                    }, 'slow');

                    prev.addClass('scroll')
                        .siblings().removeClass('scroll');
                    
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }, 0);
   } 
            }

        }
    });
```

```css
.views-row-1,.views-row-2,.views-row-3{
  min-height:100vhl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="region region-content-main">
    <div id="block-views-home-banner-block" class="block block-views contextual-links-region">
<div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first classtest" style="height: 445.781px;">div1
   </div>
  
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even classtest" style="height: 445.781px;">div2
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last classtest" style="height: 445.781px;">div3
   </div>
  </div>
</div></div>

<div id="block-views-customerspeak-block" class="block block-views contextual-links-region">

  <div class="content">
    <div id="customerspeak">
<div class="view view-customerspeak view-id-customerspeak view-display-id-block view-dom-id-4e68752def5318cb93acda980e657d95">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last classtest scroll" style="height: 432px;">
   div 4 
    </div>
    </div>
</div></div>  </div>
</div>
```